# Overwrite a button backgroundColor in react-native

Tags: css, react-native, user-interface, button, mobile

I am new on react-native and I was wondering if there is an easy way to overwrite a  backgroundColor in the button. I did try in many ways but with no luck.
Basically I am trying to replace the blue background by default with my custom color.

Any good tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
function App() {
  const [color,setColor] = React.useState('blue'); 

  return (
    <Button 
       color={color}
       title="Click here"  
       onPress={() => { setColor("black") } />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the documentation for [Button](https://reactnative.dev/docs/button) in react native,

You can easily provide the required color to color prop of Button as follows:

```
<Button
        title="Press me"
        color="black" // Color of your choice
        onPress={() => Alert.alert('Button with adjusted color pressed')}>
```